# How to create dynamically records for each month between range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, period

I have the following dates in a table cp:

```
start_date: 01/01/2017, end_date: 01/08/2017;
start_date: 01/04/2017, end_date: 01/07/2017
```

I would like to create a record dynamically for each month between these periods. It tried with the following query, but I don't understand why it's not working.

```
select add_months(cp.end_date, rownum-1) which_month, id
FROM    (select '1' as id, 
            to_date('01/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') start_date,
            to_date('01/08/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') end_date
    from dual
    UNION
    select  '2' as id, 
            to_date('01/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') start_date,
            to_date('01/07/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') end_date
    from dual) cp, all_objects
WHERE ROWNUM <= months_between(cp.end_date, add_months(cp.start_date, -1));
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Looks like a perfect case for a calendar table with some joins perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand why it's not working.

ROWNUM is a pseudo-column generated by the result set; it doesn't work the way you think.

One solution - there are several but this is the closest there is to an industry standard - is to use the `connect by level` trick:

```
select '1' as id, 
        add_months(date '2017-01-01', (level-1) ) as which_month
from dual
connect by level <= months_between(date '2017-08-01', date '2017-01-01')+1
```

`months_between()` takes the arguments `(end_date, start_date)` - you need to add one to that number to get the end date.

> "Would the level-trick still work ?"

Sort of. There's an additional trick necessary to prevent the CONNECT BY generating a product:

```
select id, 
        add_months(start_date, level-1 ) as which_month
from t23
connect by level <= months_between(end_date , start_date)+1
    --  these two lines required to avoid the need for DISTINCT
    and id = prior id 
    and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by 1, 2
;
```

[LiveSQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f0pul49e1pi9pd5ljbnnu8vy3).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. In your example the period is hardcoded, but what if you have a table containing periods (as the table 'cp' in my query) and would like to create for each month of these period a corresponding record ? Would the level-trick still work ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer of APC, which I would like to thank, I was able to create the following query:

```
select distinct add_months(cp.start_date, level-1) which_month, id
FROM    (select '1' as id, 
        to_date('01/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') start_date,
        to_date('01/08/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') end_date
    from dual
    UNION
    select  '2' as id, 
        to_date('01/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') start_date,
        to_date('01/07/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') end_date
   from dual) cp
connect by level <= months_between(cp.end_date, cp.start_date) + 1
order by id asc, which_month asc;
```

I had to use a distinct in the first select statement, but it created for each period in table 'cp' dynamic records for each month (within their respective period).

UPDATE

Using the level-trick, I was able to construct the solution:

```
select add_months(cp.start_date, level-1) which_month, id
FROM    (select '1' as id, 
        to_date('01/01/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') start_date,
        to_date('01/08/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') end_date
    from dual
    UNION
    select  '2' as id, 
        to_date('01/04/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') start_date,
        to_date('01/07/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') end_date
    from dual) cp
connect by level <= months_between(cp.end_date, cp.start_date) + 1
and id = prior id
and prior sys_guid() is not null
order by id asc, which_month asc;
```

Comment: I have expanded my answer with a solution which avoids the need for a distinct